Unable to see PRs created by renovatebot for Gitlab repos with rules
I have configured renovate with my Gitlab repo as a pipeline job. The following are rules present in my repo -
For branch names the regex pattern that is defined is - "(\d+-.+)|(stable)|(fix-.)|(revert-\w+)"
And commit messages have the pattern - '((feature|fix|refactor|test|performance|build|style|security)-[bfi]{1,3}((#\d+))|((#0-[^))]+)):\s.+)|(Merge)|((feature|fix|refactor|test|performance|build|style|security)-[bfi]{1,2}([^))]+): Review fixes)|(Squashed '.)'
By removing the rule temporarily for the branch renovate/configure, I was able to see the first onboarding commit.
Post that I haven't been able to either the Onboarding PR or the subsequent dependency related PRs even though my renovate job runs successfully.
Any help regarding this is appreciated.
This is how my config looks like
{
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
  "commitMessageAction": "build-i(#{{{issueNumber}}}):Upgrade",
  "commitMessageTopic": "{{{depName}}}",
  "commitMessageExtra": "to v{{{newVersion}}}",
  "branchPrefix": "stable-",
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "managers": ["argocd", "npm", "composer", "cargo", "gomod", "helmv3"],
      "enabled": true
    }
  ]
}

